# Vim: How to open a file whose name is determined by running a shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim

Suppose that I have a command, say `find ABCD | grep text1` which outputs full-path of a file to be opened. I know I can send this output to `vim` using `xargs` and open the file, but this is possible only in command line.

How can I do this from inside vim editor?

Comment: Do you want to `vi "$(find ABCD | grep text1)" from the commandline or do you want to `:! vi "$(find ABCD | grep text1)` from vi ?

Comment: I want everything to happen from within vim. I don't want to create a new vim process for each file I want to open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming COMMAND returns exactly the path of your file, then something like this should be ok from the command line:

```
$ vi $(COMMAND)
```

and this should be ok from within vim:

```
:e `COMMAND`
```